# Knockout JS : Function call twice time

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js, event-handling, dom-events

I added one text box and I want to do like that on every `keyup` function should be call.

This is my html code :

```
<input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" maxlength="255" data-bind="event:{keyup: doSomething},value: property1,valueUpdate:'afterkeyup'"></input>
```

This is my knockout js code :

```
define(['uiComponent','ko'], function(Component,ko) {
         return Component.extend({
            defaults:{
                property1: ko.observable(),
                tracks: {
                        property1: true
                  }
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },
            getText: function () {
                return "call the function here..";
            },
            doSomething : function(){
                this.property1.subscribe(function(newValue){
                    console.log(newValue);
                    console.log("inside subscribe");
                });
            }
        });
});
```

For example : When I Press <kbd>T</kbd> then it will call one time. After, I press <kbd>E</kbd> then it will call twice instead of once.

I want to do like that on every `keyup` I want to get textbox value.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I got my solution :**

I do like that one possible workaround is to store the returned **subscription** object when calling subscribe and if there is an already stored **subscription** exists **dispose it** before subscribing again.

```
define(['uiComponent','ko'], function(Component,ko) {
         return Component.extend({
            defaults:{
                property1: ko.observable(),
                subscription : null,
                tracks: {
                        property1: true
                  }
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },
            getText: function () {
                return "call the function here..";
            },
            doSomething : function(){
                if (this.subscription)
                    this.subscription.dispose();

                this.subscription = this.property1.subscribe(function(newValue){
                    console.log(newValue);
                    console.log("inside subscribe");
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's sort of an "anti pattern" to have two way bindings *and* subscribe to events.

In `initialzie`, create a subscription to your observable once:

```
initialize: function() {
  /* ... */
  this.property1.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* ... */ });
}
```

If you plan to remove the component later, you can store the subscription and dispose it upon removal. (Similar to what you're currently doing on every event.)

Now, whenever `keyup` happens, knockout reads the `value` from the input, writes it to `property1`, and calls the subscribed function.